# Как в плагине gulp'а require-dir пропустить выполнение некоторых заданий?

Tags: javascript, gulp, сборка

В файле gulpfile.js яиспользовал плагин require-dir, который направляет сборщик в другую папку, в которой находятся таски,разбитые на отдельные файлы. Там есть таск, связанный с удалением файлов,использующий плагин [плагин del](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md). По задумке хочется,чтобы пердначалом каждой сборки, он сносил файлы предыдущей сборки. Он их удаляет,однако возникают конфликты. Сборка стартует:

По [image: картинке]  видно,что таск удаления стартует,все идет дальше, пока не выпадает ошибка:

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/home/projectpath/build'
```

Код таска:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('delete', function () {
  return del('./build/**', {force:true});
});
```

Код таска build:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('build', ['browserify',  'markup', 'dashboard-markup', 'frontend-style', 'dashboard-style', 'frontend-images', 'frontend-fonts']);
```

Код таска default:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    config = require('../config'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('default', ['delete','browserSync'], function() {
  return gutil.log('Tasks completed!')
});
```

Предполагаю, что все дело в том,что удаление не успевает завершится и он начинает выполнят другие таски из-за чего возникает конфликт. МОжет если выставить какое-то условие, можно тормознуть другие таски, пока онв се не удалит?

Comment: Нашел промежуточное решение в каждом таске гульпа дописал ['delete'], теперь пока он не выполнится ,другие не стартуют.но думаю это кустарный способи  есть поинтереснее